# How to change app.py variable with HTML button?

Tags: python, flask

How do I add or subtract 1 from the variable num ( in flask route) with an HTML button?

```
@app.route('/')
def note():
    num = 1
    return render_template('home.html', num=num)
```

Comment: Are you using PyScript?

Comment: no I Dont @Daviid

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with callbacks in flask.
I'm more aware doing this with plotly/dash

but it should work standalone aswell like this:

---

Let's see a simple scenario:

1. User gives his/her username.
2. Our function calculates a value based on the username. Making this dummy call as time consuming call using `time.sleep` function.
3. User receives the value after the operation is being completed.

This can be achieved by using the following code.

`app.py`:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    username = None
    value = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get("username", None)
        
    def calculate_value_based_on_username(user_given_name):
        time.sleep(10)
        return len(user_given_name)
    
    if username:
        value = calculate_value_based_on_username(username)
        return render_template('app.html', username=username, value=value)
    return render_template('app.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`app.html`:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {% if username %}
      Hello {{ username }}! Length of your username: {{ value }}
    {% else %}
      Hello guest! 
    {% endif %}
    <form action="/" method="post">
      Username: <input type="text" name="username">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output]

---

Source:
[How to return a response in callback function with flask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014738/10648655)

Comment: I need to increment a value on click of a button not take user String input

Comment: I know. I'm not here to make your homework, this is an example which you can use not a  1:1 finished Code for YOUR project. this should answer everything you need to know - nobody here will do your homework for you, I think you have false expectations of SO

That's the answer I thought you needed, your question is generally not clear, I also don't get your code that you added what should this do, maybe add more detail to your question, as far as I understood this should solve your problem.

Comment: I changed the code to make it simple for you to understand, and don't be so rude

Comment: Not trying to be rude, sorry if you thought i was